# Is a teacher's recommendation in LinkedIn actually useful?

Tags: interviewing, linkedin, recommendation-letter

After graduating, I have some friends that have teacher's recommendations in their LinkedIn profile. I have had a good relationship with most of my teachers (quite good, actually) and I have been a good student, so it won't be a problem for me to get one.

After all the applications and job interviews that I have done, all the companies that have my LinkedIn (or even if I applied through LinkedIn itself), ask for the CV and look at the CV in the interview (either in person or by phone, or when selecting if you pass the first filter to even ACCESS the interview).

So before asking a teacher for a recommendation (which I think I should as it is always something possitive to have in my profile), I want to know if companies really care about that, or they would ask for a recommendation calling by phone or e-mailing the teacher itself.

Comment: It *might* help get you an interview in the first place

Comment: It's better than nothing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked,

> I want to know if companies really care about that

The answer is really, "it depends." Some employers may not even look at your linkedin profile. If they do, it certainly won't hurt for you to have a glowing recommendation, but it's not likely to significantly change someone's opinion about you.

That said, if you're a fresh grad without much practical job experience, you may need all the help you can get when landing your first significant professional job. From a hiring manager's perspective, the *best* recommendations are *specific* recommendations. No one really cares to read a bunch of ultra-generic "oh this student was so great!" recommendations. But if you have a teacher who can write a recommendation that actually shows some specific value you're bringing to the table, that can more easily make a difference. For instance,

> M.K was a pleasure to work with in my Advanced Basketweaving class - they were able to lead a team project that exceeded expectations and displayed how M.K was able to apply the material I taught to real world problems. They were also able to pick up new material and lean it independently well enough that they became a resource for other students to depend on during group study sessions.

That's the kind of recommendation you ultimately want to have on a LinkedIn profile.

You also asked,

> Or they would ask for a recommendation calling by phone or e-mailing the teacher itself

The practice of calling or emailing for recommendations or reference checks is really more of a formality for HR, versus a meaningful input for the hiring manager - although that may vary for some positions. So, the person who decides whether or not to call a reference, and what to ask them, may not ultimately be the hiring manager - and it's really the hiring manager you want to *impress* - versus the HR person, who you want to *satisfy* from a perspective of being employable in a much more general sense.

Answer (score 4):

Can't hurt.   My daughter just graduated high school and has teacher's recommendations.  It's definitely not going to hurt.

Comment: Agreed.  When first starting out this is a great idea.  After you have some professional experience, I would take it off.

Comment: Why take it off anyways? You can just add some of your bosses-managers. Maybe because it is too old once you have some professional experience? @MisterPositive

Comment: If I saw a candidate that had some real experience and still had a college or high school recommendation I might think they hadn't updated there linked in profile in some time.  Also after you have some experience your HS or College recommendation carries a whole lot less weight.

Comment: @MisterPositive Other people write the recommendations themselves. There is no need to actively delete what other people say about you, even if it is from 20+ years ago. You should actively update for the fields that you can edit yourself though.

Answer (score 2):

As others said it wouldn't hurt but it mostly depends on if the employer even looks at it. You shouldn't be shy about it either. Definitely advertise it as best as you can through your paper resume or during the interview. Make them want to look at it.

I think it's career/age dependent though on "teacher's recommendation." You wouldn't show macaroni pictures you made when you were in pre-school just as much as you wouldn't show these things 10 years into your career.

Answer (score 1):

It won't hurt, but I would not expect much from it. It will also depend on where you are applying, who the teacher is, what school, and how long ago it was when you went to school.

If you're applying for a research position at a university, a recommendation of your Nobel prize winning professor who was your advisor for the thesis you wrote a few months ago is going to have more of an impact than a recommendation of your high school's music teacher you had 25 years ago, when applying for a job as insurance agent.